# Where can I download ISO 3166-2 data?

Tags: data, standards, france

I am looking for latitude and longitude coordinates of french subdivision.

I am not used to GIS but I saw that ISO 3166-2 contains default code of such subdivisions, their name etc but where can I download the complete data in a readable format (with python preferred) with name, code and coordinates ?